# selecting and displaying all rows doesn't work?

Tags: java, sql

in my Servlet I'm calling this method:

```
            titelTabelle = DatabaseStatements.titelSuche(titel);
```

and in my jsp im trying to display the results via:

```
${titelTabelle}
```

but my method titelsuche doesnt want to select anything. I'm trying to display any value that is stored in my database, but the SELECT * FROM seminar doesn't work, even though I did the exact same stuff with other tables. Is the method wrong?

```
    public static String titelSuche(String titel) {
    String titelAusgabe = "";

    try {
        // Verbindung zur Datenbank aufbauen
        con = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM seminar");

        //pstmt.setString(1, titel);


        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            titelAusgabe= rs.getString("titel");
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have data in your in your database for seminar table? And have you tried directly executing this sql on the sql client.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, that function would return at most the first title.
To get all the titles, use code like this:

```
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        titelAusgabe += rs.getString("titel");
    }
```